# Problems with moving yesterday's files from a folder to another location

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, robocopy

I'm using the following batch script to isolate yesterday's files from the source folder.

The script works up till the part where yesterday's and today's files are moved to the *currnewer* folder.

I can't find out why I'm unable to isolate yesterday's files from the *currnewer* folder and move them to *curr folder*.

I'd be very grateful if someone can tell me what's wrong with this script.

Thanks in advance!

```vb
REM yesterdays date
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "yesterday=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"

mkdir C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\currnewer
robocopy C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\Source\ C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\currnewer\ /move /maxage:%yesterday%
mkdir C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\curr
robocopy C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\currnewer\ C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\curr\ /move /minage:%yesterday%
robocopy C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\currnewer\ C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\Source\ /move
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\currnewer
```

Comment: What happens if you do the standard thing to view what's actually happening and whether the variables are correct: remove/comment `@echo off`, add `pause` at the end and run the batch file in a Command Prompt console?

Comment: The redirection syntax `echo >file text` looks strange to me, I don't think you'll get the `*.vbs` file you expect; have you ever checked its content?

Comment: Yeah, `echo` definitely needs to be on the _other_ side of `n0.vbs`

Comment: `robocopy Source\ curr\ /move /maxage:2 /minage:1` should move yesterday's files directly...

Comment: @aschipfl `echo >file text` _will_ work (albeit with a leading space: `echo>file text` will omit it).  However, OP should definitely check the contents of the `.vbs`  to see if it has what's expected.

Comment: @TripeHound, depends on what you mean with "working"; `echo > file text` and `echo>file text` will both write `ECHO is on.` to a file (I can't test right now if the file will be called `file text`, or `file` only, ignoring `text`); however, the OP intended to write `text` to a file called `file` -- at least according to my understanding...

Comment: @aschipfl  I **can** test it right now, and your first example produces a file called `file` with `<space>text` in it; the second example produces a file called `file` with `text` in it.  Tested on both a Windows 7 and XP machine.  (The `<space>` represents a space, but SO doesn't like a space after a backquote).

Comment: @TripeHound, I'm really surprised now (I guess @SomethingDark is too?)... anyway, I recommend to write it like `> file echo text`, because the other syntax is _very_ confusing, and I'm pretty sure it does not work for all commands in general...

Comment: @aschipfl  I wouldn't _use_ the form the OP used (I normally use `echo text > file` though this has the [usually minor] disadvantage of having a trailing space at the ends of lines).  Might try to remember `> file echo text` in future as this eliminates all extra spaces (and makes it obvious the output is being redirected, which can get lost on long lines when it's at the end).

Answer (score 0):

user forfiles instead of the vbscript to work with file from the date you want and use it in combo with robocopy...

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\Source" /D -1 /C "cmd /c  robocopy @path C:\Users\ajay.shaan.shanmugam\Documents\currnewer\ /move"
```

you can specify if you want forfiles to look into subdirectory with /s and also specify a filter using /m *.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, and the example given, the script after optimization should look like this:

```vb
@echo off
set "yesterday=1"
set "Documents=%USERPROFILE%\Documents"

REM Creating directories currnewer and curr
mkdir "%Documents%\currnewer" "%Documents%\curr"

REM Moving source to currnewer (A to B)
robocopy "%Documents%\Source\" ^
    "%Documents%\currnewer\" /move /maxage:%yesterday% /L

REM Moving currnewer to curr (B to C)
robocopy "%Documents%\currnewer\" ^
         "%Documents%\curr\" /move /minage:%yesterday% /L


REM Moving currnewer to source (B to A)
robocopy "%Documents%\currnewer\" ^
       "%Documents%\Source\" /move /L

REM Remove folder currnewer (B)
rmdir /S /Q "%Documents%\currnewer"

exit /b 0
```

*note: I added `/L` to `robocopy` to list only (simulation)*